# How to get index of string found in list and equal to input string

Tags: c#, string, linq, list, indexing

I'm trying to get index number of founded string from list. I have list with 500 string number values:

```
 List<string> List = new List<string>();
```

So I if have some input string equal to some exist string in my list, for example:

```
  string numbStr = "54";
```

now I want find index of equal string in list, index of string "54" which should be index 53. So if my input string value is less the 101 I have correct results. If input value is a string "54", and I found equal string "54" in list, then index value is 53, +1 I got desired index, this way:

```
    int index = List.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith(numbStr));
```

But if my input number is bigger then 101 for example `string numbStr = "308";` index result is 517, with "500" which row is really 499 I got 901 etc. All strings in list checked and counted are equal to its indexes by sequence with shift -1 in comparing with string names.

So not sure what is the reason of this wrong results, need advice to figure out.

list looks like this, maybe because white space I'm not sure:

```
123 b4 c1 nnn
124 b4 c1 nnn
125 b4 c1 nnn
126 b4 c1 nnn
```

Comment: Try to use "Equals" method or == instead of "StartsWith" and see if it works. this is because, Starts with might lead to multiple result in any order, hence the index might be not accurate

Comment: How you are populating the input list? is that list is sorted?

Comment: @Abhilash R Vankayala hello, as with answer below I got 0 this way

Comment: @un-lucky Hello, list load string in loop one by one, and it is equal with display or printing into the text file, everything is in the order as must be. and loading occurs before this condition when list is done

Comment: If your `List<string>` has 500 values only, how can your code return values such as 517 or 901? The maximum value it should return is 500 (ie, 499 + 1).

Comment: @ Frank Fajardo yes true, but 500 just for example in my code I have 1000, but no matter same wrong results in both cases with given range. So still can't figure out

Answer (score 0):

Below line might be causing the issue where you are using `StartsWith` which matches both `12` and `123` if you pass `12` as input, for example.

```
int index = List.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith(numbStr));
```

**Solution:**

change that line of code like below and give it a try

```
int index = List.FindIndex(x => x.Split(' ')[0] ==numbStr);
```

Or simply

```
int index = List.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith(numbStr+" "));
```

**Update:**

Just to make sure you have your items in order, you can do something like this..

```
int index = List.OrderBy(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(' ')[0])).ToList()
                .FindIndex(x => x.Split(' ')[0] ==numbStr);
```

Comment: Hello, this way I got same result 0 as if use Equals instead StartsWith

Comment: @lado : are you sure there are no whitespaces in your string. Add sample array data to question.

Comment: @ DarkKnight yes there is a whitespaces. question edited, anyway not sure how to go further

Comment: with `StartsWith` if input "500" result is 901 same as shown  in my question, with `Split` again 0, and with your last update `OrderBy`  I got `IOrderedEnumareable` with `.FindIndex` no extension method could be found

Comment: @lado: check the `update` selection again. Added `ToList`

Comment: I tried this way, but got `An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Answer (score 0):

variable `List` should be `list`. Only start with uppercase if it's a property or method.

Although I find your situation hard to comprehend due to the formatting, I deducted these three assumptions:

1. The number that will be supplied as string, can **always** be found in the list.
2. Your list is ordered in the sense that it should always contain the number at the corresponding index minus 1 (list[0] == -1, list[1] == 0, etc.).
3. The goal is to check whether the supplied number string exists in the right position of the list (a unit test of the list, if you will).

Going by these assumptions, I'd say parse the string and check the specified position. This means you do not have to search the entire list for every supplied number (and is thus a lot faster).

```
var list = new List<string>() { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10' };
string test1s = "1";
string test2s = "2";
string test3s = "10";
string test4s = "11";

int test1i = null;
int test2i = null;
int test3i = null;
int test4i = null;

Int.TryParse(test1s, test1i);
Int.TryParse(test2s, test2i);
Int.TryParse(test3s, test3i);
Int.TryParse(test4s, test4i);

/* in case you do not want to unit test, 
* you can obviously do something else with the variable here.
* check on list size is to prevent index out of range exceptions and is optional */
Assert.IsTrue(test1i.HasValue && list.Count() > test1i && list[test1i-1] == test1s));
Assert.IsTrue(test2.HasValue && list.Count() > test2i && list[test2i-1] == test1s));
Assert.IsTrue(test3.HasValue && list.Count() > test3i && list[test3i-1] == test1s));
Assert.IsFalse(test4.HasValue && list.Count() > test4i && list[test4i-1] == test1s));
```